# How to input clipboard to find command?

Tags: bash, find, clipboard

What I need to do is pass a list of file names to find and have find print these files with path to xargs (find's -exec would also be fine) to carry out a command on them.

I well know that find can read a file of file names, reading lines:

```
while read line; do find . -name "$line" -exec command '{}' \; ;done <file
```

But in my case it would be more handy to have find read from the clipboard.

On the clipboard the file names are new line separated, and so when clipboard prints out, it looks like the file contents of file mentioned.

I use xsel to deal with the clipboard (in Debian Linux).  To carry out a command on all files listed on the clipboard *in the current directory* it's possible with:

```
 xsel -b -o | xargs command
```

But the idea of using find is of course to be able to search for any of these files on the list recursively.

It would be nice if the following worked, but with this find only reads the first file on the list:

```
 xsel -b -o | while read line; do find . -name "$line" -print0 | xargs -0 command ;done
```

If this is correctable then that would solve the issue.

Redirecting the clipboard (with the <) to find doesn't exactly work because bash says no such file - as find is expecting a file.

Everything would be easy if find could receive multiple names without needing to flag each pattern (ie `-name dsc456.jpg -name dsc457.jpg`) or one could bracket the multiple names to one `-name` pattern, but coming from `xsel -b -o` that could be hard anyway.

So that's where I got to and I'd like to know if some one has any idea about this!  I may have to write a script that writes the clipboard to a file and go from there.

Comment: I have not tested, but what if you turn it around? `xsel -b -o | while read line; do find . -name "$line" -print0 ; done | xargs -0 command` and probably for safety add an `-r` to the `xargs` options.

Comment: I think that might separate xargs from the while loop - bash reports "no file specified"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe to `xargs` instead of `find`:

```
$ xsel -b -o | xargs -I X -r -n 1 find . -name X -exec command '{}' \;
```

Comment: It looks good but there is no result in bash.  ...sorry, I had wrong clipboard content just now.  it works well!

Comment: I've tested it and it works on my machine. Try `--replace` if `-I` doesn't work for you.